# Is there any alternative for ComboBox in C#, UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

ComboBox is causing UI halt when data share operation is going on(App is minimized, after restoring from minimized state then halt happens). Need to use alternative solution rather than Combobox. Is there any?

Please suggest me how can i make custom control exactly like combobox.

Comment: Have you tried a dropdownlist?

Comment: couldn't you derive from `ComboBox` and override the behavior that causes the problems?

Comment: Can you change the operation to be async?

Comment: What is `data share operation`?

Comment: @zaitsman, ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs

Comment: @Ackdari , haven't found any root cause of it. adding ComboBox with no properties also creates this halt when app is minimized and restored again(then halt happens).

Comment: I doubt any other **control** can handle delay in **data**retrieval . So the actual question should be: "what causes your UI to halt" You should handle that instead.